# GWT RequestFactory - how to initialize it properly?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gwt, junit, requestfactory

My GWT applications follow MVP pattern with singleton `EventBus`, and `Display`+`Presenter` bound together in `Activity` (with help of GIN):

```
public class MyActivity implements Activity {
  @Inject MyDisplay display; //usually bound in Singleton scope
  @Inject MyPresenter presenter;

  ...
  @Override
  public void start(AcceptsOneWidget panel, EventBus eventBus) {
    diplay.bindPresenter(presenter);
    presenter.start(eventBus);
    panel.setWidget(display);
  }
  ...
}
```

Usually I inject new instances of specific `RequestFactory` into specific `Presenter` with GIN. My presenters have `start()` method, where I can pass `EventBus` instance created on behalf of the `Activity` (`ResettableEventBus`).

```
public MyPresenter {

  @Inject MyRequestFactory requestFactory;

  public void start(EventBus eventBus) {
    requestFactory.initialize(eventBus);
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I assume it is always safe, to let GIN create and inject new instance of `MyRequestFactory`. But if I want to unit test `MyPresenter` using `RequestFactorySource`, I would rather need to initialize the `RequestFactory` using:

```
requestFactory.initialize(eventBus, new InProcessRequestTransport(processor));
```

And here comes the question. Can I bind `MyRequestFactory` in scope `Singleton` (does the generated instance keep any state?), and initialize it globally with my singleton `EventBus` (does it depend on `Activity`'s `EventBus`?) - what are the consequences? I would assume that `MyRequestFactory` instance injected to `MyPresenter` is already initialized either for production, or for testing. Another solution would be to inject some additional `RequestFactory` initialization strategy into `MyPresenter`, but is it necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RequestFactory` is **designed** to be used as a *singleton*.

Assuming you also have an application-wide event bus, it'll work just the same as you use it today: RequestFactory only posts to the event bus, it doesn't listen to events.